# Testing a function that takes Model parameter in spring boot java

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, mockito

As I am new to testing in Spring Boot Java, I need to test a function that takes a model as parameter and locale like this one:

```
public void doSomething(User user, Locale locale, String any){

//instructions ---------
}
```

I dont want to do a test for a controller just imagine we have a model called User and a function that do something but takes the model as parameter and locale and something else like String.

My model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@Column(unique= true, nullable = false)
private Long id;


private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String email;

@Column(length = 60)
private String password;


private boolean enabled;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(name = "users_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", 
referencedColumnName = "id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = 
"role_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
private Collection<Role> roles;


private String secret;
//getters and setters

}
```

Comment: This is too broad. Can you be more specific about which part you need to know about?

Comment: I need to pass a model User in the test function as well as locale but dont know how? I think it is not efficient to write all data model (username, password, role, etc..) and pass them as collection or something? or there is something that could be done by mockito or anything else?

Comment: Just instantiate the User and set the fields to whatever values you need. Should be no reason for mocks. Use mocks for collaborators like services or daos

Comment: thank you @NathanHughes that was helpful

Answer (score 2):

Unit-testing Spring controllers directly is usually not very helpful, because Spring MVC relies on "magic" that's not there in a plain unit test.

Instead, I'd recommend to use the [**Spring MVC Test Framework**](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/testing.html#spring-mvc-test-framework), or MockMVC. It lets you fire virtual requests against your controller, set request header and body and make assertions based on the virtual response sent back. These tests are formally integration tests, but they usually don't require external dependencies, and you'd use Mockito or a similar framework to abstract away service dependencies. Here's an example test (taken from the Spring reference section linked above):

```
@Test
void getAccount() throws Exception {
    this.mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/1")
            .accept(MediaType.parseMediaType("application/json;charset=UTF-8")))
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType("application/json"))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.name").value("Lee"));
}
```